# Can two JS functions run simultaneously?

Tags: javascript

I have heard that JavaScript is a single-threaded, but I am unsure of what that really means.

For example, say we have to functions:

```
const func1 = () => {
   console.log(1)
   console.log(2)
}
const func2 = () => {
   console.log(3)
   console.log(4)
}
```

Assuming all logging is done from these two functions, and each function is only called once; is it possible to log anything other than

```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
```

and

```
> 3
> 4
> 1
> 2
```

?

Or is it possible to logout something like

```
> 1
> 3
> 2
> 4
```

?

I have not been able to achieve the latter.

Comment: Here's an introductory reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: No, it's not - that's basically what people mean when they say JS is single-threaded.

Comment: You might be able to get mixed output by running the functions in WebWorkers.